# Localizing a rails ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, i18n-gem

I'm writing a rails gem that provides some partials and assets that I'd like to translate. So far the partials and assets work in the main rails app just fine, but I don't know how to have it register the localizations (I keep getting "translation_missing" errors). I've been looking online and I can't find any guides to localizing rails gems.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was put my locale YAML files under /lib//rails/locales/ in my gem.